# Browsers no longer reporting js errors - YUI history manager

Tags: javascript, yui, error-reporting

I'm using YUI's browser history manager, and my browsers no longer report runtime errors. They will still show a parse error in the error console, but if I call a bogus function, for example, inside some event handler, the browser just stops all js processing it seems. Even firebug's debugger will just quit when I get to a line with an error. Anyone else seen this? Is it even YUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Turns out the answer to this question is here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521521/yui-customevent-no-errors-being-reported)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to this problem ( which I've experienced a couple times now ) is to create an entirely new profile.  I haven't narrowed down what exactly is going wrong with FF but my money is on a weird combination of Firebug, web developer tool bar, and one other extension.  If firebug is missing or the web developer toolbar is missing in a FF profile, it doesn't happen.

Getting closer to storing my firefox profile in svn but it only happens every few months and not everyday after I recreate my profile.

As a half-assed solution, I keep a personnel and developer profile in Firefox now and the extensions I need for the developer profile on one of my websites.